# Why does passing children affect Typescript errors?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I seem to have encountered an odd scenario where the Typescript compiler is confused by the passing of the `children` prop to component, resulting in unsafe behaviour.

I want to have a component which can accept `subtitle` (text) and `subtleSubtitle` (boolean which affects the style) props ONLY if a `title` prop is also passed. If a `subtitle` is passed but no `title`, this should be a Typescript error.

However, when trying to implement this I found that Typescript seems to allow invalid props to be passed to the component.

Here is the code

```
import React from 'react'

// subtitle and subtleSubtitle are only permissible when title is present.
type Props = 
  | {
      children: React.ReactNode;
      title: string;
      subtitle: string;
      subtleSubtitle?: boolean
    }
  | { children: React.ReactNode; title?: string }

// Plain function to test behaviour outside of React components
const myFunc = (props: Props) => {
  if (props.title && 'subtitle' in props) {
    console.log(props.title + props.subtitle)
    return;
  }

  console.log(props.title)
  return;
}

// Component which accepts the same props
const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  if (props.title && 'subtitle' in props) {
    return (<div>
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <p style={{ color: props.subtleSubtitle ? "grey" : "black" }}>{props.subtitle}</p>
    </div>)
  }

  return <h1>{props.title}</h1>
}

myFunc({ subtitle: "some text" }) // Expect error as subtitle can only be passed if title is passed
myFunc({ subtitle: "some text", children: <p>hi</p> }) // Expected same error but there is none

// same as above, expect an error
const MyParentComponent = () => {
  return <MyComponent subtitle="some text" />
}

// Expected error but there is none
const MyOtherParentComponent = () => {
  return <MyComponent subtitle="some text">Hello</MyComponent>
}
```

Playground link:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOABRzAGc4BeOAbzjQAtgAbACZEAdgC5ExGADpk6GADkIgpAG44MYDH5IJTGFGAiA5uqYBXAEabtuuPsMmzV2wGUXWnQH4JliBB0UETgAXzgAH05uPiFRCTkMWSklFXUbbz0DI2NQ8gB6PPp+FCM4THMRDGAIYJgIDSR9OC04AHdoAGsWCHMYJmAVOAhMSXluXEgRJBE+0jQappBKADEKtDY4AAowRiYJBghmAEo2AD5OUjhmke3d6XTaADJHggtrTyR8ZuCdw6YTjiXK7jERMAJIaT8CDGW5-e4fOAAajgv2Y0jeDyOQKuRBg5igIlUQJC5Cu81B4Mh0NhaMxQNx+MJpBJpAKcAAwhMatN4K0+Lw4Og0EgwH0NDxaEwUCBaKimHMFvAALKUTngbkzeJSaTLdkAHgOzHO7Bp-zOFyuwBucvhtjgz1eHlsX1KcoB2LgDIJWz1gmAADdTh6rnqeABGU4cG0PEJ6vLhoPA4F6sD2Kg6VgcLjzKFQCQ2jE6dzvO1eOAAImMREo5bgEnLlmKaA6tZCIUjBadOljeTAieTeT9gaxVxZOKQeO9oYjUbuMbjCeZ5CWq0qmy4GI+9bBMoaAA8YK2TmyAKJ7mgYOBIKA4KCClibu1oIJDET8ShwSyylBMJhIQTXBoCLACwYA-n+gikCuazrvYXZ2OWO60DASAHuWAA00QCMI0wSCmpx8HGfahMehRnheKEAVKu7Xren69OK160CBcAiNy+SFNRtA-oKfj+kgmGoRRgrBLR0AKqCyqUHQKCiDAaqTDyGybCcrDnIC46TsEeoqgpGrwI+GaIbgyGoYecB5EGLKnueSAYP+V43tA9HwDAEpEM0LBsVMElNCqADybnXjJcl6VMMzKap6n0hOjJwDpqpcuFBnwawxm7ihaGnAAEkg-BQnGulJTyVmkEAA

Comment: It doesn't throw an error because it you pass it valid props ```{ subtitle: "some text", children: <p>hi</p> }``` is a valid object of type ```{
      children: React.ReactNode;
      title: string;
      subtitle: string;
      subtleSubtitle?: boolean
    }```

Comment: It's not valid, that type requires `title` as well

Comment: If we remove `children`, then everything works fine. `type Props = { title: string; subtitle: string; subtleSubtitle?: boolean } | { title?: string }`. Then something like `const x: Props = { subtitle: "some subtitle" }` doesn't compile, as expected. When children are added everything breaks down for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy to think that `Union Types` are exclusive, but they are actually a bit different, from `Typescript` docs:

> It might be confusing that a union of types appears to have the intersection of those types’ properties. This is not an accident - the name union comes from type theory. The union number | string is composed by taking the union of the values from each type. Notice that given two sets with corresponding facts about each set, only the intersection of those facts applies to the union of the sets themselves. For example, if we had a room of tall people wearing hats, and another room of Spanish speakers wearing hats, after combining those rooms, the only thing we know about every person is that they must be wearing a hat.

You want your types to be exclusive, so that only **one** type will be passed without intersection. This can be done by using typescript's `Conditional Types`:

```
type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never }
type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U
```

Now you can:

```
type Props = XOR<{ children: React.ReactNode; title: string; subtitle: string; subtleSubtitle?: boolean }, { children: React.ReactNode; title?: string }>

myFunc({ subtitle: "some text" }) // Error
myFunc({ subtitle: "some text", children: <p>hi</p> }) // Error
myFunc({ title: "cool", subtitle: "some text", children: <p>hi</p> }) // Works
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Typescript doesn't prevent you from having additional properties on an object, so something like this compiles just fine:

```
type Props = 
  | {
      title: string;
      anotherProp: boolean;
      subtitle: string;
      subtleSubtitle?: boolean
    }
  | { anotherProp: boolean; title?: string }

const x: Props = { anotherProp: true, subtitle: "what" }
```

This is because `{ anotherProp: true }` is assignable to the `{ anotherProp: boolean; title?: string }` type. The `subtitle` property is ignored as an "extra" property on the object.

It should be possible to avoid this issue by structuring the union type differently or by using a tagged union (though tagged unions for props of a component is rather unusual and would be a strange DX)